# How can I get all the name parts of all the second choices in a json object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

This is the full object that I want to get something from is:

```
{
    "name": "permissions",
    "description": "Get or edit permissions for a user or a role",
    "options": [
        {
            "name": "user",
            "description": "Get or edit permissions for a user",
            "type": 2, 
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "get",
                    "description": "Get permissions for a user",
                    "type": 1, 
                    "options": [
                        {
                            "name": "user",
                            "description": "The user to get",
                            "type": 6,
                            "required": true
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "channel",
                            "description": "The channel permissions to get. If omitted, the guild permissions will be returned",
                            "type": 7,
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "edit",
                    "description": "Edit permissions for a user",
                    "type": 1,
                    "options": [
                        {
                            "name": "user",
                            "description": "The user to edit",
                            "type": 6,
                            "required": true
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "channel",
                            "description": "The channel permissions to edit. If omitted, the guild permissions will be edited",
                            "type": 7,
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "role",
            "description": "Get or edit permissions for a role",
            "type": 2,
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "get",
                    "description": "Get permissions for a role",
                    "type": 1,
                    "options": [
                        {
                            "name": "role",
                            "description": "The role to get",
                            "type": 8, 
                            "required": true
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "channel",
                            "description": "The channel permissions to get. If omitted, the guild permissions will be returned",
                            "type": 7,
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "edit",
                    "description": "Edit permissions for a role",
                    "type": 1,
                    "options": [
                        {
                            "name": "role",
                            "description": "The role to edit",
                            "type": 8,
                            "required": true
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "channel",
                            "description": "The channel permissions to edit. If omitted, the guild permissions will be edited",
                            "type": 7,
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get all of these name attributes from the first json object and assign them all to different variables in javascript? How can I achieve this?

Permissions ---> role ---> edit ---> channel (In other words I want to get all of the name parts in all the second choices in the json object)

Comment: Hello, What exactly is a "choice"? Can you give more explanasion or maybe the output you wish to have from this json?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that JSON structure is fixed then it will be easy.

Consider your json is assigned to `permissionJson` then you can write it as

```
permissionJson.name  // permissions
permissionJson.options[1].name. // role
permissionJson.options[1].options[1].name // edit
permissionJson.options[1].options[1].options[1].name // channel
```

if JSON structure is dynamic then you might need loops to extract the options array index 1 element at each level and find its name.

Comment: _"Consider your json is assigned to `permissionJson` then you can write it as"_ - No, because [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) has to be parsed first

Answer (score 0):

first of all i want to make clear that i don't understand your question very well. So correct me if i misunderstood something.
you said you want to get all name parts in all second member of options(root one) array. so all you have to do is

```
JSON_DATA.options[1]
```

Here you have selected whole `role` object. to get more deeper you can use dot operator. For instance Permissions ---> role ---> edit ---> channel. this could be accessed by this line `JSON_DATA.options[1].options[1]`
it will return this

```
{
  "name": "channel",
  "description": "The channel permissions to get. If omitted, the guild permissions will be returned",
  "type": 7,
  "required": false
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**This solution works generic for as deep as the object might get in the future**

This is the solution for you: Just use this function, and create the variable `allSecondNames`:

```
const allSecondNames = [];
func = a => {
  if (a.name) allSecondNames.push(a.name);
  if (a.options) func(a.options)
  if (a[1] && a[1].name) allSecondNames.push(a[1].name); 
  if (a[1]?.options) func(a[1].options)
}
```

Sending your JSON to function `func` would put in variable `allSecondNames`:

```
["permissions", "role", "edit", "channel"]
```